# What is this weird JPEG TIFF hybrid image and how can I save it from PS as a normal JPEG?

Tags: photoshop, jpeg, tiff

I have this JPEG image saved out of PS using "Save As" and selecting "JPEG".

- It's abnormally large for it's WxH resolution
- Mac Preview's info shows it as an uncompressed TIFF
- Trying to save it out of PS with 0 quality makes no difference

Source image: https://digital-origins-public.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/what-is-this.jpg

[image: Save As Dialog from PS]
[image: Mac Preview Info Dialog]

1. What is this thing?
2. How can I save it out of Photoshop as a normal JPEG using "Save As"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run the file through [ExifTool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), you'll see that it contains a huge number of `Document Ancestors` elements:

```
Document Ancestors              : 0, 0000A6C7815905497C2762FB3073AC1B, ...
...
Warning                         : [Minor] Extracted only 1000 photoshop: DocumentAncestors items. Ignore minor errors to extract all
```

If you remove all EXIF data (`exiftool -all=`), the remaining file is only 792KB in size.  AFAIK, Photoshop will remove these unnecessary metadata when you use `Save for Web`.

There's also a thread about this phenomenon:

- Adobe Support Community: [Inflated JPG File Size - Photoshop Document:Ancestors Metadata](https://community.adobe.com/t5/Photoshop/Inflated-JPG-File-Size-Photoshop-Document-Ancestors-Metadata/td-p/8055434)

Comment: It's not necessary to remove all metadata. Just the XMP-related tags: `exiftool -xmp:all= image.jpg`

Comment: While I'm marking your answer correct, sadly it doesn't give me a way to save the file without this extra data using "Save As". I need that because we are saving a lot of these files using scripts and "Export" or "Save for Web" are not compatible.

Comment: Actually, that link you gave has a script to remove all of that garbage! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by its "magic number" bytes (`FF D8 FF E1`), it is a JPEG file in [EXIF fomat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif). You are probably more accustomed to the JFIF format. Note that in the EXIF format (which is a "container" format) there are several possible encodings for the image itself, including the TIFF format.

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems like the image (JPEG you provide via URL) is ordinary JPEG file with some hidden information inside (Steganography). You can check this [Q/A](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2144/77753) for more information. It incorporate binary codes `C3 BF` (can be decoded as ÿ). The total size of included information is 2.7MB. You can test it [here](https://stylesuxx.github.io/steganography/).

P.S. You can save it (after open in PS) via usual way: File->Save As, or use File->Export->Export As (for more options)